# Mecer laptop gives me a white screen when I close the screen

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, white-screen

I'm having a very strange hardware issue with my Mecer m770u laptop with intel i7 quad core, etc... I'm wondering if anyone has had this issue with any other brand/model of laptop, and what I should fix/replace to solve it...?

Basically when I close the screen of the laptop, the screen often goes completely white. If I open it slowly and smoothly again, the screen returns to normal. But if I close the screen when the computer is off, and then switch it on, it boots with a white screen, and opening it slowly/smoothly doesn't help. I have to then switch it on and off a few times before it returns to normal. Makes travelling with my laptop really difficult! Any suggestions?

Comment: What about this question makes it a bad question? How can I ask it in a better way?

Comment: I guess people are down voting because the problem very likely relates to a hardware fault which should be dealt with by the manufacturer.

You should mention if you've searched online or contacted the manufacturer, if the laptop is new/old etc.

Comment: It does seem like a hardware issue... thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

if your lap is still under warranty, is the best choice, otherwise
look like a cable or lid sensor, probably inverter failure,

http://www.laptoptips.ca/hardware/lcd-failures/

i am currently the same failure in an acer laptop,
cable failure is a common failure in acer laptops

regards

cancun technician